# If statement error on null string value

Tags: asp-classic, if-statement

```
<html>
<title>Test</title>
<body bgcolor="FFFFFF">

<%
sort = CStr(Request("sort"))
search = CStr(Request("search"))
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=123;Persist Security Info=True;User   ID=sa;Initial Catalog=asdf;Data Source=WIN-123"

Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
If sort = "ascending" Then
SQL = "select top 50 * from asdf order by Name"
ElseIf (search Is Not Nothing)
SQL = "select * from asdf WHERE name = '" & search & "'"
Else
SQL = "select top 50 * from asdf"
End If
rs.open SQL, conn
%>
<center><form acion="index.asp">
Search Name:<input name="search" /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form></center>
```

I'm getting an error on my

```
Else If (search Is Not Nothing)
```

line, from what I can tell it should work. and of course I also cannot for some reason browse my site on my server to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to include parameters.  Use parameterized queries instead.  You probably want to avoid using the "sa" user logon on SQL server too.  Currently your code could exposes your site and network to all manner of malicious attacks.  Search "SQL Injection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on my IIS 5, without `option explicit`, when you use

```
search=CStr(Request("search"))
```

your `search` has been initialized to `string` (`VarType: 8`).

So even if `search` is "empty", you can not use `IsEmpty` or similar function/statement to see if it's empty. Use

```
ElseIf search<>"" Then
```

directly.

Also, remember to sanitize your SQL queries...

Comment: "sanitize your SQL queries" what does that mean? How is it done?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones It simply means "avoid SQL injections and stuffs".

Comment: AnthonyWJones I used a regex with a alphanumeric pattern and a regex.replace on my input variables.  Here is what I used: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/ASPScripts/PrintPage.asp?REF=%2Fwebtech%2F112702-1.shtml